# Prevent iPhone using car audio for calls but allow music

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I connected my iPhone to my father's car stereo. I denied it access to my contacts etc.

I can now play music on my iPhone though the car stereo. Unfortunately, even if the car stereo is playing other audio (radio/SiriusXM/etc...) anytime I try to make a call, receive a call, or check voice mail the car stereo switches to playing the call through the car.

How can I make it so only music goes through the car stereo (same as a Bluetooth speaker?) and not calls?

note: in Settings->Bluetooth->NameOfCar->Device Type I tried setting it to "Headphone" but no luck. I also tried setting it to "Speaker" but no luck. No idea what those settings even do. ‍♂️